# SQL создание таблицы

Tags: sql

При вводе следующего кода

```
CREATE TABLE numbers (
   id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
);
INSERT INTO numbers VALUES (1);
INSERT INTO numbers VALUES (2);
SELECT * FROM numbers;
```

Выходят ошибки:

```
Error: near line 1: in prepare, near ")": syntax error (1)
Error: near line 4: in prepare, no such table: numbers (1)
Error: near line 5: in prepare, no such table: numbers (1)
Error: near line 6: in prepare, no such table: numbers (1)
```

При двух и более столбцах ошибки нет.

Comment: Попробуйте убрать запятую `KEY,` -> `KEY`

Comment: SwaD, получилось, спасибо